# What the fastest to post million requests with url, headers, and body?

Tags: python

I have the static url, headers, and data.
Is it possible to make million post requests simultaneously with python?
This is the file.py:

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://abcd.com"
headers = "headers"
body = "body"
resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
json_resp = json.loads(resp.content)["data"]
print(json_resp)
```

Comment: You could do it with threads, but if you post to the same site rapidly you may be stopped by a rate limiter.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use some python tools for that such as:

- https://locust.io/

Your file would look like:

```
  from locust import HttpUser, task, between

  class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
      
      @task
      def task_name(self):
          self.client.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
```

You could feed it to locust in such a way:

```
locust --headless --users <number_of_user> -f <your_file.py>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways, which is the best method and idea of `async` work
The second method is `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which I do not highly recommend

there's a example for do this.

```
# modified fetch function with semaphore
import random
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        delay = response.headers.get("DELAY")
        date = response.headers.get("DATE")
        print("{}:{} with delay {}".format(date, response.url, delay))
        return await response.read()


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    # Getter function with semaphore.
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url, session)


async def run(r):
    url = "http://localhost:8080/{}"
    tasks = []
    # create instance of Semaphore
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)

    # Create client session that will ensure we dont open new connection
    # per each request.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url.format(i), session))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

number = 10000
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```